# Chart JS - Bubble Chart is not getting rendered when loaded Dynamically

Tags: chart.js

I would be glad if anyone can help me fix the problem i'm facing with Chart Js's Bubble Chart.

I am loading the chart dynamically based on change in drop down selection.

- switch case is as below:

  ```
    case "bar":
    case "bubble":
    case "line":
        return {
            type: value,
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        data: data,
                        fill: false,
                        backgroundColor: colorCodes.chartBackGroundColor,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        borderColor: colorCodes.chartGraphBorderColor,
                        hoverBorderWidth: 2
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: false
                },
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                layout: {
                    padding: 20
                },
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                hover: {
                    animationDuration: 0
                },
                tooltips: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                animation: {
                    "duration": 1,
                    "onComplete": function () {
                        if (data.length > 0) {
                            var chartInstance = this.chart,
                                ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
                            ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize,
                                Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle,
                                Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                            ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
                            this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                                var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                                meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                                    var data = data[index];
                                    ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y);
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    scaleOverride: true,
                    yAxes: [
                        {
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: chartTypeAndLabelConfig.yAxis.title,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontColor: "#1c969c"
                            },
                            display: true,
                            gridLines: {
                                display: true,
                                borderDash: [4, 2]
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    xAxes: [
                        {
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: chartTypeAndLabelConfig.xAxis.title,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontColor: "#1c969c"
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        };
  ```

the returned config is stored into a variable "chartConfig" and then the chart is created as below:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, chartConfig);
```

When dropdown is changed from bar to line or line to bar the chart is rendered, when i try to select bubble, i see same values plotted against x-axis and y-axis without any bubbles in the chart.

Example:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5];
labels = [a,b,c,d,e];
```

when dropdown option for bubble is selected i get the chart rendered as:

[image]

When rendering chart dynamically, i'm also destroying the previously rendered chart and then rendering the chart based on the new config i get.
Is there anything i'm missing here?

Comment: appreciate the efforts on editing the problem on errors and typo's James Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you need to convert the data into a format supported by bubble charts. For line and bar charts data can be *integers* or *floats* but for bubble charts they need to be *Objects* with a specified 'x', 'y' and 'r' (radius) value.

So for example to display a data in a bubble graph at point (1,4) with a radius of  10, you'll specify it as:
{x: 1, y: 4, r: 10}

One way of doing this could be to call a helper function before creating a bubble chart or storing a copy of the data as an Object to be used only for bubble charts. It really depends on how you've set up your project and if you are concerned about the number of computations carried out or not. Hope this helps!

[Documentation for Chart.js Bubble Chart Data Structure](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bubble.html#data-structure)

Comment: This works damienHelper. The issue was with the format of data sent to bubble chart.

Comment: Damien - i have another question on the same issue.
Suppose i do not destroy the initial chart object, but then get the chart object and then do   ->  
`var chartComponent = this.chart;
chartComponent.type = "bubble";
chartComponent.update();
`
here i would be updating the type from bar chart to bubble chart. w/o modifying the data, the bubble chart gets rendered. Any clue on why this works and not when the config with just data in plain array of numbers wont ?

Comment: Ah I didnt consider that, its possible that chart.js natively supports data conversion from simple data arrays to Bubble objects, essentially doing the work for you! Thats also a cleaner way of doing it

Comment: Problem i'm facing now is, i have a drop down which has chart type with data options, so for me when the drop down changes to a different chart type, its a new data on the whole, i need to perform formatting data, add animations and set scales n all those things. I think i need a way to set data to bubble with x,y and r format with only one dimensional array and have labels at values for ticks.

Comment: i did the below to get the labels as option for ticks in x-axis:

Comment: `ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: false,
                                    userCallback: function (label, index, labels) {
                                                    return labels[index];
                                                }
                                            }`
but the plotting is starting from 0 though i have set beginAtZero: false

Comment: Its possibly due to the index having a value of zero at some point? You can either make sure that doesn't happen or try messing around with specifying the `suggestedMin` or `min` ticks option.

Comment: Thanks Damien. Can you help me the below issue. Thanks in advance - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63111230/chart-js-to-set-font-size-and-color-for-the-values-displayed-on-top-bubble-cha